# In PhotoSwipe, menu in modal window does not show up

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, cordova, jquery-mobile, photoswipe

I'm Using PhoneSwipe, jQuery Mobile, PhoneGap and Xcode to develop an app for a magazine. 
So far so good, but when it comes to display images, the modal window does not work, and I haven't figured out why.

I checked the code with Chrome's Code Inspector and Firebug and everything seems to be ok, there are no errors nor warnings, but still whenever I click on an image, I cannot return to the main gallery. The image is opened in a modal window, but the menu to manipulate the gallery does not show up.

I compare my code with the example code and it is practically the same, so I don't understand what is going on with my app.

I uploaded the www/ folder from my PhoneGap project to the server, you can check it out here:
http://www.celebrityeventsmagazine.com/app/

and this is what I'm trying to achieve:

http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/04-jquery-mobile.html

I'd like to know what is going on because I haven't been to debug the problem.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it was a CSS problem
for some reason, the photoswipe.css file was being loaded but not being interpreted, I changed the order of loading the css files and the problem was gone.